# Disable gzip in the response and enable range headers in redhat openshift

Tags: redhat, node.js, openshift-online-2

I deployed a node js application in the openshift cloud hosting. And i noticed that all the responses have gzipped automatically and the range headers got missing in every response header. Although I enable the range header but still its getting changed in the middle layer (don't know where).

Can someone suggest me how to enable range header and disable gzip.

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift's routing layer may be failing to forward that particular header.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978344/openshift-access-control-allow-origin-set-by-server-for-get-request-disappears/23996204#23996204